# Can you distribute a Safari App Extension *outside* the Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, safari, mac-app-store, osx-extensions, safari-app-extension

The [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) says this:

> To deliver an OS X app extension, it’s recommended that you submit
>   your containing app to the App Store, but it’s not required.

And the [Safari App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319-CH15-SW1) says this:

> Safari app extensions are bundled inside an app and distributed
>   through the App Store.

Does anyone know, if it's possible to distribute a Safari App Extension with an app *outside* the Mac App Store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just confirmed on macOS 10.12.4 and Xcode 8.3: you **can** distribute Safari App Extensions outside the Mac App Store!

I tested this just now by:

1. Making a new Mac app in Xcode and adding a Safari Extension to it.
2. Archiving the app & exporting it with my Developer ID certificate.
3. Sending the resulting app to a friend, who opened it on their Mac and had the extension correctly show up in Safari.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: To clarify, is developer ID needed for this to work?

Comment: FYI, this will only work on 10.12+, macOS 10.11 and lower will not automatically install this (Tested with 10.11.6 and Safari 9.1.3). @gaelan You can develop an extension without the dev ID but you will need one to distribute it

Comment: I dont know what the difference between a Safari extension and a Safari App Extionsion is, but does this approach also work for iOS safari?

Comment: but update mechanism wont work in this way

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute your Safari extension outside of the Mac App Store, via the Safari Extension Gallery. Those two options require being signed up as an Apple Developer. You can still distribute your extensions outside of these two stores, but your users will get a warning.

Comment: Asking specifically about a Safari *App* Extension, not a vanilla Safari Extension

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this, it seems Apple now restricts Safari extensions to distribution through the Mac App Store:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/659029

Otherwise, if you follow the steps to archive the app and export the notarized version, the app will open perfectly but requires "Allow Unsigned Extensions" to be checked in Safari for the extension itself to work.